# How can I see all thumbed-up songs on Pandora?

Tags: pandora

I want to see all the thumbed-up songs for one of my Pandora stations but when I go to the station's page I can only see 5 thumbed-up songs with no option to get a full listing of them. How do I get the full list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to the station's settings (by clicking the arrow near it and pressing "Edit"), scroll down to the "Thumbed-up Songs" section, then press "Show All" (located on the bottom left of the list).

Comment: I am on the page you suggested, however I do not have the "Show All" option anywhere on the page. Can you double-check if you can see Show All? (perhaps they removed it)

Comment: @Best: I can see it. Which browser are you running? Are you running any user scripts? Could you take a screenshot and paste it in your question?

Comment: Thanks @Senseful! It was my browser. Firefox on MacOS (and perhaps my AddIns) look like they hid the show all functionality. Switching to IE on PC fixed it.

Comment: This no longer works. Pandora's new interface only allows you to click to see 5 more thumbed-up songs at a time... a pain when you have hundreds!

Comment: It now shows at least 10 at a time

Answer (score 19):

I wanted to see a list of all the songs I've liked (and remove duplicates), but Pandora's UI has made it awfully hard to view all of them at once.

I ended up making http://pandorasongs.oliverzheng.com/ to retrieve the list.

Comment: This is an excellent site/app/page!

Comment: awesome..I was able to find a song I thumbs up'd yesterday and add it to spotify

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer that works outside of US!

Comment: For this to work, make sure your Pandora profile is Public. It will not work with Private profiles.

Comment: Doesn't work with the new pandora website?

Comment: This site is down.

Comment: Gives me stations but they ain't mine =)

Comment: It used to work but is stop working recently... A shame, it was great

Comment: The hosting service the site is on only gives a certain numbers of free hours of usage per month. The site will be back up at the start of next month.

Comment: @OliverZheng That's right, thanks. But even with the service back, the app doesn't work... It doesn't get any songs and it throws the following error in console: `tracking.js:11 GET http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.1.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ tracking.js:11
(anonymous) @ tracking.js:11`

It'd be amazing if you could fix it. This is better than the rest of the options here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This. Works perfectly, but: *make sure your profile is public on Pandora* or this won't work. It can't break into Pandora @Metafaniel.

Answer (score 6):

Similarly to @MTsoul, I've written a service to help get liked songs on Pandora that supports direct conversion to JSON or Grooveshark, Spotify and Last.fm playlists. It also has a method for retrieval on non-public accounts.

<strike>http://pandora-extractor.appspot.com/</strike> (no longer online)

Comment: Still having "Grooveshark" there in the answer and in the service makes it SO outdated... However, it works listing the songs. This really needs more features to be fully useful.

Comment: @Metafaniel :) maybe I'll update it

Comment: No longer online.

Answer (score 4):

Run the following (JavaScript) code in your web browser's 'console' window:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.thumb_up_list .show_more').last().click();
}, 2000);
```

Eventually, all of your 'likes' will be listed.

Comment: Heh, that's interesting. It gave me a bunch of duplicates. Apparently, I thumbed down "Mr Brightside" 157 times. Maybe I ran it too quickly.

Comment: This works.. but it starts duplicating the list if you let it keep running.  But if you just search for the first one, find the second time it shows up, and copy from above that, it works well.

Comment: This no longer works.  This uses jQuery, and I think Pandora stopped including jQuery in their pages.

Comment: @cowlinator I haven't used Pandora in a long time but my snippet could probably easily be converted to vanilla JavaScript (i.e. to not rely on jQuery).

Answer (score 2):

If you click the "My Profile" link, you can then click "Likes" on the side... it will show you all.  It's not sorted per-station though, but it does tell you under which station you did the thumbs-up on... I think that is the best you can do on Pandora's new design.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me today :

```
setInterval(function() {
$('#track_like_pages .show_more:visible').last().click();}, 2000);
```

It should avoid having duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the current app only reveals 100 songs from a thumb-up list, but the entire list can be viewed using a web browser (which can't be done from a smart device). I'm curious if the app is only playing rated songs from the 100 it has listed, or if the entire list plays but is just not viewable. While the latter would be far better, it sucks either way. I don't know why Pandora can't get their user interface right.

Comment: I feel like now it's the other way around - mobile devices only

Answer (score -1):

New update you can find songs in your "thumbs radio" playlist

Answer (score -1):

If you go into the app on your phone, and click the "Profile" button on the bottom right of the screen it will give you a list of all the songs you have liked under the "Thumbs" tab.