# Is there a way to export list of Pandora songs that I have upvoted or downvoted?

Tags: export, pandora

Is there a way to export a list of songs that have been upvoted or downvoted in a particular pandora station?  I have been working on customizing my own pandora station for over a year and would like to be able to get that data out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see all thumbed-up songs on Pandora?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7658/how-can-i-see-all-thumbed-up-songs-on-pandora)

Answer (score 9):

[Songs (You) Liked on Pandora](http://pandorasongs.oliverzheng.com/) is a nice page/app to get a list of songs you've liked (up-thumbed). You could probably request songs you dis-liked (down-thumbed) from the author/creator.

Comment: Doesn't work with the new pandora website design.

Comment: Please fix this service: it was great but stopped working...

Comment: Just tried it and it worked for me

Answer (score 6):

There is a good [Google Chrome Extension to export Pandora Thumbs Up](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cgkmfkggcmoclhipfkabaemflflellek) playlists to Spotify.
Once you have the playlists in Spotify, you can export it using the tips here:
http://www.spotify-forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=15

I'm sure you'll find other tools to export Spotify playlists.

Comment: This extension no longer exists

Answer (score 5):

In your profile you'll see the list of thumbed up and down songs.  You could always just do the ol' copy/paste/clean up - shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 5):

I created a small script to export your entire list of liked songs, see here: http://www.tedtrowbridge.com/exporting-liked-songs-from-pandora/

The solution works by using a little bit of javascript to navigate to your 'likes' page, then automatically click the 'show more' button continuously while scraping the songs title/artist.  All songs are displayed so they can be easily copy-pasted at the end.

You can also find the project on GitHub: https://github.com/teddytrowbridge/pandora-export

Comment: Looks like it answers the question, but can you give a bit more detail here on what this does / how this works?

Comment: I forked your GitHub page for bookmarks, works well: https://github.com/sethismyfriend/pandora-export/blob/master/README.md

Comment: There's some good talk about this method on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Pandora/comments/6og294/pandora_australia_users_i_wrote_a_script_to/ Here's a pastebin copy of a winning script: https://pastebin.com/9br3VZjX

Comment: Thank you @Foliovision, this method worked for me in 2019 unlike almost all of these other solutions

Comment: The links by @Foliovision still work great in 2021. I just exported a list of more than 7,000 thumbs-up/down ratings by following the directions on the Reddit link.

Answer (score 2):

I opened all of my stations one by one and copied and pasted each song into Excel.

Then, I cleaned everything up.

1. Find and Replace: replace the word *by* with >
2. Data: Text to Columns. Use > as the delimiter to separate the song from the artist.
3. Removed all duplicates.
4. Pasted into [Playlistity](http://playlistify.org/)

Worked like a charm!

Comment: Note that playlistity no longer exists

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a few different options, but the easiest to use seems to be [Pandora Extractor](http://pandora-extractor.appspot.com/)

There are two ways to use it. First, if you have a public profile on Pandora and have under 100 likes, you can simply type in your Pandora username (no password required) and the script will look at your public profile and scrape your likes.

Alternatively, if your profile is private, if you have over 100 likes, or if the other option doesn't work for some reason, you can simply open up Pandora in a new tab, navigate to your profile page, and then drag and drop the "Drag to Pandora Tab" button from the Pandora Extractor to your Pandora tab. This used to work for me on Chrome, but no longer. It may still work on Firefox though.